# im getting 3 errors. ; is expected and having else without if. how do i fix them?

Tags: java

i am getting 3 errors. on line 32 and 35 where i am creating instances and it says ; is expected towards the end of each instance and having an else without an if. how can i fix this?

```
public class BookTest {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double charge;
        double grandTotal= 0;           

        String dataArray[][] = {{"NonFiction", "Abraham Lincoln Vampire Hunter","Grahame-Smith","978-0446563079","13.99","Haper","NY","US","Political"},
                    {"NonFiction", "Frankenstein","Shelley","978-0486282114","7.99","Pearson", "TX","England", "Historical"},
                    {"Fiction", "Dracula","Stoker","978-0486411095","5.99","Double Day", "CA","4918362"},
                    {"NonFiction", "Curse of the Wolfman"," Hageman","B00381AKHG","10.59","Harper", "NY","Transylvania","Historical"},
                    {"Fiction", "The Mummy","Rice","978-0345369949","7.99","Nelson","GA","3879158"}};

        Book bookArray[] = new Book[dataArray.length];
        int quantityArray[] = {12, 3, 7, 23, 5};

        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
            if (dataArray[i][0] == "NonFiction")
                bookArray[i] = new NonFictionBook(dataArray[i][0], dataArray[i][1], dataArray[i][2], dataArray[i][3],
                Double.parseDouble(dataArray[i][4]), new Publisher(dataArray[i][6], dataArray[i][7]), dataArray[i][8], dataArray[i][9]));
            else
                bookArray[i] = new FictionBook(dataArray[i][0], dataArray[i][1], dataArray[i][2], dataArray[i][3],
                Double.parseDouble(dataArray[i][4]), new Publisher(dataArray[i][6], dataArray[i][7]), dataArray[i][8]));
        }

        String msg = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < bookArray.length; i++) {
            charge = bookArray[i].calculateTotal(quantityArray[i]);
            grandTotal = charge + grandTotal;
            msg += String.format("%s  %s  $%.2f\n",bookArray[i].getTitle(), bookArray[i].getIsbn(), charge); 
        }

        msg += String.format("Grand Total  $%.2f ",  grandTotal);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Put braces around your `else` and `if`.

Comment: Remove one of the two last parentheses in 'dataArray[i][9]));' -> 'dataArray[i][9]));' and 'dataArray[i][8]));' -> 'dataArray[i][8]);'. You code inside both if and else is still one instruction, so braces are not needed. However it might be clearer to read the code if you put braces around code inside if and else.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to put brases around your code. This will make it easier for the compiler to see what is wrong.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++)
{
        if (dataArray[i][0] == "NonFiction")
        {

        bookArray[i] = new NonFictionBook(dataArray[i][0], dataArray[i][1], dataArray[i][2], dataArray[i][3],
            Double.parseDouble(dataArray[i][4]), new Publisher(dataArray[i][6], dataArray[i][7]), dataArray[i][8], dataArray[i][9]));
    }else
    {
            bookArray[i] = new FictionBook(dataArray[i][0], dataArray[i][1], dataArray[i][2], dataArray[i][3],
            Double.parseDouble(dataArray[i][4]), new Publisher(dataArray[i][6], dataArray[i][7]), dataArray[i][8]));}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have extra parenthesis on those lines.

It should be

```
if (dataArray[i][0] == "NonFiction")
    bookArray[i] = new NonFictionBook(dataArray[i][0], dataArray[i][1], dataArray[i][2], dataArray[i][3], Double.parseDouble(dataArray[i][4]),
            new Publisher(dataArray[i][6], dataArray[i][7]), dataArray[i][8], dataArray[i][9]);
else
    bookArray[i] = new FictionBook(dataArray[i][0], dataArray[i][1], dataArray[i][2], dataArray[i][3], Double.parseDouble(dataArray[i][4]),
            new Publisher(dataArray[i][6], dataArray[i][7]), dataArray[i][8]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You SHOULD put braces around long if statements, as it makes your code more readable, but thats not your error. Your error is that you have a closing parentheses ")" more than you should at the end of the line, just before the semicolon ";"

So your code should be like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        if (dataArray[i][0] == "NonFiction") {
            bookArray[i] = new NonFictionBook(dataArray[i][0], dataArray[i][1], dataArray[i][2], dataArray[i][3],
                    Double.parseDouble(dataArray[i][4]), new Publisher(dataArray[i][6], dataArray[i][7]), dataArray[i][8], dataArray[i][9]);
        } else {
            bookArray[i] = new FictionBook(dataArray[i][0], dataArray[i][1], dataArray[i][2], dataArray[i][3],
                    Double.parseDouble(dataArray[i][4]), new Publisher(dataArray[i][6], dataArray[i][7]), dataArray[i][8]);
        }
    }
```